# renderInContext consumes a lot of memory and eventually crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

My `UIView` is very large and I'm trying to convert it into a pdf. I am using `renderInContext` for generating image of a `UIView`. After executing `renderInContext` the memory goes up by 100 MB only for 1/6th of the view.

If the whole view is rendered, then the memory goes to around 350 MB or so in simulator but it'll crash in device. I have tried rendering view part by part, but the memory keeps increasing.

The allocated memory isn't being released immediately after creating the image. I have tried changing imageNamed to imageWithContentsOfFile but no luck.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

I have referred to many answers but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated...

Here is the code for generating image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(aView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 0);
[aView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then I use this image to convert to pdf file. But while executing renderInContext I'm getting a memory spike. It then never lowers.

Comment: Share some code block where you call `renderInContext`, maybe you have some retain cycle. Who knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer might help someone so I'm answering it.

For large drawing, I had to use `drawViewHierarchyInRect: afterScreenUpdates:` but it should be executed inside an `autoreleasepool`. If not the memory keeps on rising.

For smaller drawing `renderInContext` is better.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using renderInContext recently and while it's very taxing on the CPU I saw no effect at all on memory usage. Are you able to use the alternative: `drawViewHierarchyInRect: afterScreenUpdates:` It's much faster for me so I guess it may also be more efficient and help with your memory issue.

That method renders to the context and then you can just call:

```
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
```

Comment: I used drawViewHierarchyInRect: afterScreenUpdates: but the memory still rising.

Comment: Have you profiled it in instruments to find out where the memory is leaking?

Comment: I used profiling. But there was no memory leak. The memory kept on increasing.

Comment: You'll need to share more code, it's impossible to figure out the issue without the code.